# css adjust previous sibling properties

Tags: html, css

Im trying to adjust the previous sibling when the first sibling has a hover state. I have put together an example here. Im trying to get it to stay at 100% width of the viewport and adjust the div you are hovered over to be 60% and the other child to be 40%.

https://jsbin.com/xucipevuzi/edit?html,css,output

This gets the next sibling but i cant find a good way to get the previous when the first one has a hover.

```
&:hover
  width 60%
  + div
     width 40%
```

Comment: There is no previous selector in css, I suggest to do it with js

Comment: You can't get the previous sibling in CSS. You would have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CSS selector going back up the HTML tree ( **Cascaded** Style Sheet
)

for this case, you can set every `div` to `40%` when hovering parent and `60%` when hovering parent and hovering the `div` :

```
.two-selection:hover div
      width 40%    

.two-selection:hover div:hover
      width 60%
```

https://jsbin.com/risenihejo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Elegant solution.